# With HanekeSwift, will network requests be cancelled automatically for off-screen cells?

Tags: swift, haneke

When using [HanekeSwift](https://github.com/Haneke/HanekeSwift) with a table view, I can simply show an image inside a cell with:

```
cell.image.hnk_setImageFromURL(url!)
```

without any further control.

If I scroll the table view quickly, some cells will go off the screen without showing their images since these images are not downloaded yet.

Are the network requests for these off-screen cells cancelled by HanekwSwift automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the HanekeSwift contributors told me that the answer is NO and I should call `hnk_cancelSetImag`e in `prepareForReuse`. Therefore, I added following lines in my class inherited from `UITableViewCell`:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()

    compImage.hnk_cancelSetImage()
    compImage.image = nil 
}
```